# Gesture recognition with Unity, Oculus Quest and the Oculus Quest Integration package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to implement hand gesture recognition for Oculus Quest with Unity and the Unity Oculus integration package.

I've read the "Hand Tracking in Unity" documentation on the Oculus developer website, but they only talk about getting the current pinch of the fingers, which is not what I want:
https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-handtracking/

I thought about getting fingers flexion for each finger (with a value between 0 and 1 for example), and then training a k-NN model with the 5 features to then be able to recognize the nearest gesture. But I've been searching for hours and didn't find anything about getting finger position, the only thing I found is getting the pinch.

By looking in the `OVRSkeleton.cs` file (from the Oculus Integration package), I've been able to get the current Transform for each bone (so the position as a vector and the rotation as a quaternion), but I don't really know how to calculate or get an estimate for the finger flexion with that (or anything useful to perform gesture recognition)

```cs
OVRSkeleton skeleton = GetComponent<OVRSkeleton>();
skeleton.Bones[(int) OVRPlugin.BoneId.Hand_Index1].Transform.position
skeleton.Bones[(int) OVRPlugin.BoneId.Hand_Index1].Transform.rotation
```

The list of bones IDs is in the ["Hand Tracking in Unity" documentation page](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-handtracking/#understanding-bone-id).

In fact, what I want to implement seems to look exactly like this package:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/vr-hand-gesture-recognizer-oculus-quest-hand-tracking-168685

Any help, ideas or comments about how to calculate fingers flexion, or any other solution to implement gesture recognition would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

*A few things/links I've explored so far:*

- https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusQuest/comments/elrn7a/unity_hand_tracking_and_different_gestures/
- https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/89615/detect-custom-hand-gestures

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jorgejgnz/HandTrackingGestureRecorder  is something im trying currently, the docs dont say it has a depenedency, but apparently it does, and i dont have it working yet.
you can access the bone rotations at runtime and compare those to a recorded gesture.  i think its closer to "template matching" than machine learning, measuring the error between two poses.

Comment: Yeah I found it too a few hours after posting this! And it works perfectly for me, I only had to download the `GestureRecognizer.cs` file (the other is not needed), and follow the instructions in the readme. It works by finding the saved gesture which minimize the sum of distances between the current and saved finger tips positions for each finger, which is really smart and works like a charm